# For loop multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to excute for loop on parallel. How can I do that?

for example:

```
def foo():
    # brahbrah

for i in range(0,5):
    foo()
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you heard of multithreading? Check it out, maybe it could help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you consulted the threading and multiprocessing docs? Does foo need shared state?

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def foo():
    # brahbrah

def func(count):
    foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    count = 5
    results = pool.map(func, range(count))
    pool.close()  # 'TERM'
    pool.join()   # 'KILL'
```